# Vue2 change object property from method param passing into child props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

oi, this one seems so simple but it's giving me a headache.

I have a child component with a property passed down:

`<dialog-child requests='requests'/>`

the passed prop, is an object obtaining varied booleans. The dialog is v-modeled to in this case,

```
<dialog v-model='request.deleteItem'>
```

```
requests { deleteItem: false, editItem: false, syncItem: false,  }
```

When I click on the delete button, I want to make a request to delete an item, and pull up this dialog component. This works fine if i simply change the bool in the object to true, but I need more control by passing the @click to a method and passing a parameter.

```
<btn @click='makeRequest(deleteItem)'>Activate Dialog</btn>
```

so in the method, I need to figure out how to say that the passed deleteItem, is request.deleteItem and then I would make it true.

```
makeRequest(requested){
//somewhow say 
this.requests.requested = true
}
```

### How could I pass in the parameter to take control of the objects property?

I could do a long form of multiple if checks, if requested = '' then make this prop true, but that feels gross.

I also need to pass in a second param, item after I figure this out - so to pass in two params do i just say methodName(param1, param2) and on click method(item1, item2) or do I need to create an object like method({item1, item2})?

Comment: the syntax you're looking for is `this.requests[requested] = true`

Comment: Fantastic. This works for the console log, but its not changing the component prop. Is there a way i need to return this?

Comment: it doesnt seem to actually be changing the prop. console.log(this.request.deleteItem); shows after we change it, and it doesnt flip.

Comment: ah, props are read-only.  to change a prop value you must emit the new value and have the parent component change it.  the prop should then update inside the child component.

Comment: i fixed this by changing the param to a string, and removing the request for a second item. Onwards to a item pass in too.

Comment: i wish there wa sa reply button here lol - the parent is making the change, I have the param as methodName(param) not methodname('param') so all fixed. Any idea how to add a second param to a method? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have everything nice and neat :) but:
For that we need option "to emit event on child component" but Vue.js does not work like that. So try this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <dialog-child requests='requests' @resetRequest="resetRequest()"/>
        <btn @click='makeRequest("deleteItem")'>Delete</btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DialogChild from 'Dialog.vue'

export default {
    components: { "dialog-child" : DialogChild },
    data() {
        return {
            requests: {
                makeRequest: false, //New Field
                deleteItem: false,
                editItem: false, 
                syncItem: false
            }

        }
    },
    methods: {
        makeRequest(action) {
            //So here you can create new request Object with whatever you want. Use action argument to check what you want to do here...
            let newRequests = {
                makeRequest: true, 
                deleteItem: true,
                editItem: false, 
                syncItem: false
            }

            //Then this newRequest object need to copy to this.requests, this will update request object reference, and trigger "watch" in child component
            this.requests = newRequests;
        },
        resetRequest() {
            //Request object is again updated with new reference, but makeRequest is false so it will not trigger action in Dialog Child component
            this.requests = {
              makeRequest: false, //Now this is false,
              deleteItem: false,
              editItem: false, 
              syncItem: false
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>


//And child component should be like this

<template>
  <div>
  </div>   
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { 
    requests: { Type: Object }
  },
  watch: {
    requests(newVal) {
      if(newVal && newVal.makeRequest) {
        this.doStuff()   
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doStuff() {
      //So after doing what you want, you need to make event to reset requests
      this.$emit('resetRequests');    
    }    
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this by changing the param to a string, and removing the request for a second item. Onwards to a item pass in too.